# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError after running Dijkstra's algorithm in an adjacency matrix

Tags: java, dijkstra, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to print the shortest path after running Dijkstra's algorithm in a weighted adjacency matrix. I am getting a stackoverflow error when trying to printout the path.

I have tried changing the start node into a type long and BigInteger as advised by previous answers on this platform also I am aware that I am using a recursive method whereby that problem lies.

```
import java.util.*;

public class djikstra {

private static final int invalid = -1;

public djikstra(int matrix[][],int start) {

    int numVertices = matrix[0].length;
    int [] distances = new int [numVertices];
    boolean [] isAdded = new boolean[numVertices];

    for (int i=0;i<numVertices;i++) {
        distances[i]= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        isAdded[i] = false;
    }

    distances[(int) start]=0;
    int [] parents = new int [numVertices];
    parents[start] = invalid;

    for(int i=1;i<numVertices;i++) {
        int closestNeighbour = -1;
        int shortDist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for(int j=0; j <numVertices;j++) {
        if(!isAdded[j] && distances[j]<shortDist) {
            closestNeighbour = j;
            shortDist = distances[j];
        }
    }
    isAdded[closestNeighbour]=true;

    for(int j = 0; j <numVertices;j++) {
        int edgeDist = matrix[closestNeighbour][j];
        if(edgeDist > 0 && ((closestNeighbour+edgeDist)<distances[j])) {
            parents[j] = closestNeighbour;
            distances[j] = shortDist + edgeDist;
        }
    }
}
    printSol(start,distances,parents);
 }

private static void printSol(int start,int[] distances,int[] parents) {
    int numVertices=distances.length;
    for(int i=0;i<numVertices;i++) {
        if(i !=start) {
            path(i,parents);
        }
 }
}

private static void path(int curr,int[]parents) {
    if(curr== -1) {
        return;
    }

    path(parents[curr],parents);

}
}

public static void Main(String args[]){
       int matrix2[][]= {{0, 0, 0, 4, 12, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0}, 
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 8, 0, 18, 15, 7},
           {0, 0, 0, 11, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 8, 10}, 
           {4, 0, 0, 0, 10, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 13, 0}, 
           {0, 0, 3, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 5, 11}, 
           {0, 0, 3, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 5, 9 },
           {20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 10, 20, 16, 22, 0, 0}, 
           {0, 12, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,14, 0, 4, 6, 12, 0,0, 0 },
           {0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 4, 0, 10, 14, 20, 0, 0}, 
           {0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 10, 0, 18, 0, 0, 15 },
           {0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 6, 11, 11}, 
           {0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 5, 11}, 
           {0, 0, 8, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 5, 0, 8}, 
           {0, 7, 10, 0, 11, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 8, 0}};

    djikstra doDjikstra = new djikstra(matrix2,0);
}   



Expected results:
0 4 13 1
Actual results:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at helperclasses.djikstra.path(djikstra.java:61)
```

Comment: You need to debug this in detail. And you also need to remember which "node" you already visited.

Comment: I’m not sure if that is a Dijkstra algorithm. In Dijkstra, starting with your start node, you visit a node, put it in a visited set (which i could not find), calculate and set or update total distance for all neighbours (which i found), put them in an unvisited set (by isAdded), set or update their predecessor (seems to be in parents, i’m not sure if it works for a not already added node), and continue with the unvisited node with the smallest total distance (which i did not find). You visit every node in a fixed but random order.

Comment: Also, i do not know what your path(int, int[]) does. It calls recursively the parent of each node until the start node is reached, and returns nothing?

I put the code in Eclipse. After fixing some things (class name starts with an uppercase letter, while the main method starts with a lowercase m), i got the same error. The debugger showed me that only the nodes with no. 1 and 13 are called. Each is the parent of the other. As they call themselves in a loop, all other nodes (esp. start node 0 which has -1 as parent) are never called. Looks as if indeed your Dijkstra implementation is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StackOverflowError` is triggered by an infinite recursion in the `path` method.
`parents[curr]` never holds -1 (the base case), therefore the recursion never stops.
You will need to ensure that `path` is called with -1 for `curr` eventually.